# Anyway to get taylorotwell/laravel-oauth2 package to work with Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-4, oauth-2.0

There are some packages that I want to use with Laravel 4.1, but I am forced to use Laravel 4.0 because the package taylorotwell/laravel-oauth2 that I have built my Facebook auth on, is only compatible with Laravel 4.0.  Is this are an updated version of this?  Or another version that is compatible with Laravel 4.1?  What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used [artdarek/oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) for lots of different login providers (oauth1 and oauth2) and was very happy using it. the project itself also has good examples to get started with any login provider and works with 4.1.